# How to build a SQL query for the below requirement?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's suppose and `EMP_Table` consists of following columns

```
EMPID,SAL,DEPTID,MGRID
```

`Req:` List all managers whose salary is `>`  all of team members salary

Sample Input:

```
EmpID            SAL             DEPTID             MGRID
101              10000              A                102
102              30000              A                102  
103              15000              A                102
104              10000              B                106
105              30000              B                106  
106              45000              B                106
107              50000              B                106  
108              20000              C                109
109              50000              C                109 
110              45000              C                109
```

Expected output:

```
EmpID            SAL             DEPTID             MGRID
102              30000              A                102
109              50000              C                109
```

Comment: What have you done already? Show us your query please.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT M.EmpID, M.Salary, M.DepId, M.MgrId
FROM dbo.Employee E INNER JOIN
     dbo.Employee M ON
     E.EmpID = M.MgrId
WHERE E.Salary >= (SELECT MAX(DE.Salary) FROM dbo.Employee DE WHERE DE.DepId = E.DepId)
AND M.Salary >= E.Salary
```